# State or Visitor Permits for Drivezy/Self Drive Cars in India?

Tags: road-trips

I am travelling to Goa from Pune in a Karnataka passing Drivezy car. I am told that the car has national permit and all the necessary documents like valid insurance, road tax, self drive etc. As I will be driving from Pune through Karnataka and finally into Goa, will I be required to pay any visitor / road tax or any similar thing. If yes, how much will it cost. 
I also heard that commercial vehicles, including Drivezy cars, are not allowed on the Mumbai Bangalore expressway. Is this true?