# How to get a state permit for a rented self driven car from Kolkata to Bihar?

Tags: indian-citizens, india, permits

I am travelling in a self driven rental car from Kolkata to Bihar via Asansol - Dumkar Road, where can I get the state temporary permit for a week?

Comment: There was a similar question, recently, that got no answers: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/154364/state-or-visitor-permits-for-drivezy-self-drive-cars-in-india

Comment: @Amrit Raj Have you tried asking the rental company?